# Hiding a progress bar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am using a progress bar which I want to appear when a button is clicked. After I get a list populated, I want the progress bar to disappear. Below is my code:

```
<div class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"/></div>
if (source_names_list.length == 0)
{
  // want progress bar to appear

}
if (source_names_list.length > 0)
{
   // want the progress bar to disappear
}
```

I tried setting the visibility and it doesn't help. i tried adding the progress bar programmatically.

Comment: Add a class which does display: none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the display property via CSS.

```js
var source_names_list = []

if (source_names_list.length == 0)
{
  // want progress bar to appear
  document.querySelector('.progress').style.display = 'inheret'

}
if (source_names_list.length > 0)
{
   // want the progress bar to disappear
   document.querySelector('.progress').style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">Progress</div>
<div class="indeterminate"/>Indeterminate</div>
```